# Apply parent style to specific child only

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

```css
.ctr {
  text-align: start; // Apply to first child
  text-align: center; // Apply to second child
  text-align: end; // Apply to third child
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctr">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Since the box are **inline-block**, they respect the **text-align** property.

Now I would like to apply `text-align: start` to the first **box**, `text-align: center` to the second **box** and so on...

Expected Result
[image]

Comment: Please provide a picture of the desired outcome because the question unclear

Comment: @vsync please check

Comment: As I suspected, you are asking the wrong question. What you are after is to evenly-spread a container's children across the horizontal axis. I will prepare you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To evenly-spread the children (across the horizonal axis)

You can use flexbox on the parent (`.ctr`) as shown below:

```css
.ctr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctr">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

---

##### As-per your request - without flex/grid:

```css
.ctr {
  text-align: justify;
}
.ctr::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to achieve what I'm proposing without flex or grid.

Comment: @ibrahimxcool -it is - see my updated answer. This used to be the way many years ago, before `flexbox`

Comment: Perfect.... But could you please explain why ...`.ctr::after` is necessary?

Comment: `text-align: justify` will not really do much unless it "thinks" the children are taking the whole horizontal space.

Answer (score 1):

Use the :first-child, :last-child, and :nth-child pseudo-classes in your specific case, but on the "box" class, not on the "ctr" class itself.

```css
.box:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    }
.box:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
}
.box:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

If you have multiple items and want a default one, you can put a "default" value. In the following example you can have more than three "box" divs and all except the first and last would be centered.

```css
.ctr .box {
    text-align: center;
}
.box:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.box:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Note that there are a number of approaches to this, but if you follow this approach, the ordering of the CSS DOES matter. For example, if you put the ".ctr .box" line at the bottom then ALL values will be center aligned.

Answer (score 0):

CSS nth-child(n) let's you select a specific child of a parent.

```css
.ctr>*:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: start;
}

.ctr>*:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}

.ctr>*:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: end;
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctr">
  <div class="box">box 1</div>
  <div class="box">box 2</div>
  <div class="box">box 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What i want is to apply the parent style to specific child only.... where box 2 should be in the center and box 3 should be at the end

Comment: Sorry, I don't at all understand. in what way are the styles not being applied to a specific child? Perhaps there is some confusion about what the width of the parent should be? Or maybe you are looking for flex or grid to position the actual elements not just the text?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to space the boxes out, you can use flex (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). You can replace `space-between` with `space-around` to add more space on the left and on the right.

```css
.ctr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctr">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

This is an example of doing it without flex:

```css
body {
  margin: 16px
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box:first-child {
  position: absolute;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctr">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to achieve what I'm proposing without flex or grid.